# Discord.js Reaction issue

Tags: discord, discord.js

When I react to a message in the channel "idere" whith  then it sends the message to "idere-accepted" and when I react with  then it sends the message to "idere-declined" and this is what I have made

But this is the issue when I all ready reacted to one message and want to react to an other message that are send in "idere" with  then it sends the message 2 times in "idere-accepted" and when i react third time it send the message 3 times The issue is the same for

````js
const emojiChannelName = "idere";
const emojiChannelNameAccepted = "idere-accepted";
const emojiChannelNameDeclined = "idere-declined";

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.guild.id === guildID) {
    if (message.channel.name === emojiChannelName) {
      if (message.author.id !== botID) {
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
      }
    }
    client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
      if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
      if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

      let channelAccept = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
        (channel) => channel.name === emojiChannelNameAccepted
      );

      let channelDeclined = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
        (channel) => channel.name === emojiChannelNameDeclined
      );

      if (user.bot) return;
      if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

      if (reaction.message.channel.name === emojiChannelName) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
          if (user.id === config.owner) {
            if(message.author.id !== botID) {
              let accept = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor("GREEN")
              .setTitle("Ide accepted")
              .setDescription(
                `${message.author} Havde en ide som er\n**${reaction.message.content}**\n(Testing)`
              )
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(`Accepted af ${user.username}`);
              await channelAccept.send(accept);
              reaction.message.delete();
            }
          } else {
            reaction.message.reactions
              .resolve("")
              .users.remove(reaction.users.cache.keyArray()[1]);
          }
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
          if (user.id === config.owner) {
            let declined = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor("RED")
              .setTitle("Ide declined")
              .setDescription(
                `${message.author} Havde en ide som er\n**${reaction.message.content}**\n(Testing)`
              )
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(`Declined af ${user.username}`);
              await channelDeclined.send(declined);
              reaction.message.delete();
          } else {
            reaction.message.reactions
              .resolve("")
              .users.remove(reaction.users.cache.keyArray()[1]);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Where you have sent the message, you can try returning the message instead.

Try this:

```js
const emojiChannelName = "idere";
const emojiChannelNameAccepted = "idere-accepted";
const emojiChannelNameDeclined = "idere-declined";

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.guild.id === guildID) {
    if (message.channel.name === emojiChannelName) {
      if (message.author.id !== botID) {
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
      }
    }
    client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
      if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
      if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

      let channelAccept = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
        (channel) => channel.name === emojiChannelNameAccepted
      );

      let channelDeclined = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
        (channel) => channel.name === emojiChannelNameDeclined
      );

      if (user.bot) return;
      if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

      if (reaction.message.channel.name === emojiChannelName) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
          if (user.id === config.owner) {
            if(message.author.id !== botID) {
              let accept = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor("GREEN")
              .setTitle("Ide accepted")
              .setDescription(
                `${message.author} Havde en ide som er\n**${reaction.message.content}**\n(Testing)`
              )
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(`Accepted af ${user.username}`);
              await channelAccept.send(accept);
              return reaction.message.delete(); //returns the message delete
            }
          } else {
            reaction.message.reactions
              .resolve("")
              .users.remove(reaction.users.cache.keyArray()[1]);
          }
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
          if (user.id === config.owner) {
            let declined = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor("RED")
              .setTitle("Ide declined")
              .setDescription(
                `${message.author} Havde en ide som er\n**${reaction.message.content}**\n(Testing)`
              )
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(`Declined af ${user.username}`);
              await channelDeclined.send(declined);
              return reaction.message.delete(); //returns the message delete
          } else {
            reaction.message.reactions
              .resolve("")
              .users.remove(reaction.users.cache.keyArray()[1]);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The issue is still there whit your code

But ty for the try